# Adjoint operator of a functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $\Omega$ a compact space, $J:\Omega\times\Omega\to \mathbb R$ a symmetric function and $\theta:\Omega\to [0,1]$ a continuous function taking values in $[0,1]$.

Let ${\mathcal L}$ the operator defined on functions $f\in L^2\big(\Omega\times\{1,2\}, \mathbb R\big)$ as
\begin{align}
{\mathcal L}f({x, i})=&\chi_{1}({i})\bigg({\int_{\Omega}({1-\theta(y)})J(x, y)(f({y, 1})-f({x,1}))dy+\int_{\Omega}\theta({y})J({x, y})({f({y,2})-f({y, 1})}dy)}\bigg)\\
&+\chi_{2}({i})\int_{\Omega}({1-\theta({y}))} J({x, y})({f({y, 1}))-f({x,2})}dy,
\end{align}
where $\chi_1(x)$ denotes the characteristic function centrated in $1$, that is $\chi_1(x)=1$ if $x=1$, $\chi_1(x)=0$ if $x=2$.

How can I compute the adjoint operator of $\mathcal L$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is $\chi_1(i)$?  Is $\chi$ a characteristic function?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Presumably the indicator function of $\{1\}$, i.e. $\chi_{\{1\}}(i) = 1$ if $i=1$ and $0$ if $i=2$.

Comment: Yes, $\chi$ is the characteristic function.

Comment: Another question to ask - who is $\theta(y)$? The Heaviside step function?

Comment: Why not use $\langle g, {\cal L}f\rangle = \langle {\cal L}^* g, f\rangle$ ?

Comment: @Math1000 $\theta$ is a function defined in $\Omega$ and taking value in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yet another question to ask - how are we defining the inner product on $L^2(\Omega\times\{1,2\},\mathbb R)$? Normally an inner product is defined on a Hilbert space, not the product of a Hilbert space with e.g. $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @Math1000 It is clearly a Hilbert space isomorphic to $L^2(\Omega)\times L^2(\Omega)$

Comment: Okay, so $$\langle f(x,i), g(x,j) \rangle = \begin{cases} \langle f(x), g(x)\rangle,& i=j\\ 0,& i\ne j\end{cases} \quad \mathrm ?$$

Comment: @Gribouillis I tried to do what you suggest but I had some problems with the computations. Anyway I will post my computations in a while in order to explain better the problem. Thank you for your help.